# Rewriting data to disk

Tags: c++

I ask user for input and write this data to disk. However I want the user to be able to update some of this data. It writes the data the first pass of the loop. But the second loop is not updating the description. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct LabData {
    int recordNumber;
    char desc[16];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    FILE *file = fopen("myfile.txt", "wb+");
    if(file == 0)
        std::cout << "ERROR FILE IS NULL!";

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        LabData lb;
        lb.recordNumber = i;
        std::cout << "Enter a description: ";
        std::cin.getline(lb.desc, 15);
        if(fwrite(&lb, sizeof(lb), 1, file) != 1)
            std::cout <<" ERROR IN WRITE!";
    }

    LabData lb;
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        fseek(file, i * sizeof(LabData), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&lb, sizeof(LabData), 1, file);

        if(lb.recordNumber != i)
            std::cout << "Wrong record!";
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Record number: " << lb.recordNumber << " Description: " << lb.desc << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter new record description: ";
            std::cin.getline(lb.desc, 15);
            if(fwrite(&lb, sizeof(lb), 1, file) != 1)
                std::cout <<" ERROR IN WRITE!";
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        LabData lb;
        fseek(file, i * sizeof(LabData), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&lb, sizeof(LabData), 1, file);
        std::cout << "Record number: " << lb.recordNumber << " Description: " << lb.desc << std::endl;

    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should be using a database or at least something with structure rather than an unmanaged text file.  Is the updated data being written to the end of the file or not showing up at all?

Comment: not being shown at all

Comment: and what does the debugger show is happening

Comment: So, you have put c++ but you are using c-style file descriptors and functions. Please consider using iostream! It will make your life so much easier: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Reading/writing structs directly as binary like that isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: did you od the file to see whats actually getting written?

Comment: also calling this file xxxx.txt is misleading, this is a binary file, editing it in vi will only lead to tears

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `fseek(file, i * sizeof(LabData), SEEK_SET);` before writing into the file, in the second loop,

```
std::cout << "Record number: " << lb.recordNumber << " Description: " << lb.desc << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter new record description: ";
std::cin.getline(lb.desc, 15);
fseek(file, i * sizeof(LabData), SEEK_SET);
if(fwrite(&lb, sizeof(lb), 1, file) != 1)
    std::cout <<" ERROR IN WRITE!";
```

Once you read from the file, you have to seek back to rewrite the data in same place.